# Amazon was IAM setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a free aws account and when as a user I face these issues in IAM console :-

User: arn:aws:sts::551485096929:federated-user/A is not authorized to perform: iam:GetAccountSummary

User: arn:aws:sts::551485096929:federated-user/A is not authorized to perform: iam:ListAccountAliases

I cannot create role, see users or groups basically I have no privileges all the while being root.How do I solve this?

Comment: As what IAM user did you login to AWS? Or did you use a URL to sign in which did not ask for username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is no such things as a "Free AWS Account".

When a new AWS account is created, it can take advantage of the [Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), which provides are certain limited set of services at no charge. If you use services that are not included in the Free Usage Tier, or use more than the free tier quantities, you will be charged for usage of those services.

As to the inability to perform account-related activities, you should either:

- Use your Root credentials to access account information (the username and password used to setup the account), or
- Configure your account to permit IAM users to manage billing-related information, see: [Granting Access to Your Billing Information and Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/grantaccess.html)